# Getting "{"message":"Invalid value \"undefined\" for header \"Content-Type\""}" error when tried to download a container file

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I used the below code to get the file from azure container.

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const url = `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net}`;
const blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(storageAccountName, accessKey, url);

const read = blobSvc.createReadStream(containerName, fileName);

res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', read.contentType);
readable.stream.pipe(res);
```

But, when I download the text file, i m getting `{"message":"Invalid value \"undefined\" for header \"Content-Type\""}` in the file.

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const url = `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net}`;
const blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(storageAccountName, accessKey, url);

const properties = blobSvc.getBlobProperties(
containerName,
fileName,
function(err, properties, status) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(502, "Error fetching file: %s", err.message);
    } else if (!status.isSuccessful) {
        res.send(404, "The file %s does not exist", fileName);
    } else {
        return properties;
    }
});
```

)

return properties;

In this function, for the first call, it is returning null, during the second call there are values poping out, but it is useless, as the await is not working in this case and the thread finishes with undefined value. Is there is something I'm missing out?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(read.contentType)` ?

Comment: The issue is that `blobSvc.createReadStream` returns you a readable stream and that does not have `contentType` property.

Comment: Is there anyway to retrive the content type??

Comment: Provided an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because `blobSvc.createReadStream` returns you a stream and that does not have `contentType` property.

If you need to send the content type in the response headers, you would first need to fetch the blob's properties and use the `contentType` property from there.

Here's a sample code (untested) for this (Ref: https://willi.am/blog/2014/07/03/azure-blob-storage-and-node-downloading-blobs/):

```
blobSvc.getBlobProperties(
    containerName,
    fileName,
    function(err, properties, status) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(502, "Error fetching file: %s", err.message);
        } else if (!status.isSuccessful) {
            res.send(404, "The file %s does not exist", fileName);
        } else {
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`);
            res.setHeader(Content-Type', properties.contentType);
            blobService.createReadStream(containerName, fileName).pipe(res);
        }
    });
)
```

Comment: I have use the following code.blobSvc.getBlobProperties(
    containerName,
    fileName,
    function(err, properties, status) {
        if (properties) {return properties
    });
)     //It seems that for the first time i cant get the properties, but during second call, it is loaded. unfortunately the node thread is not waiting for this result. I have added await and async too. nothing helps.. Is there something I'm missing out?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the latest code as an update. Also, please include the complete code where you're calling the above code.

Comment: const azure = require('azure-storage');
const url = `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net}`;
const blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(storageAccountName, accessKey, url); 
  const properties = await blobSvc.getBlobProperties(
    containerName,
    fileName,
    function(err, properties, status) { if (err) {
            res.send(502, "Error fetching file: %s", err.message);
        } else if (!status.isSuccessful) {
            res.send(404, "The file %s does not exist", fileName);
        } else {
            return properties
        }
    });    return properties;

Comment: Please do not put code in comments. Edit your question and include the code there instead.